# Playing sounds in perfect succession on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, audio

I am developing a game for the iPhone and iPad using cocos2d, and I need to be able to play a sound exactly when another one completes.
I have a soundtrack that is chopped up in smaller pieces, and there are no room for the tinyest gap between playback when one finishes and one starts.

Btw. I cannot glue the sounds together into a single file and just play that since the order of the files will be rearranged runtime.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CocosDenshion you can register a delegate with

```
 [[CDAudioManager sharedManager] setBackgroundMusicCompletionListener:self  
                                        selector:@selector(musicDidFinish)];
```

[CDAudioManager class reference](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/CocosDenshion/html/interface_c_d_audio_manager.html)

This delegate will be called whenever the background music ends. This of course only works if you play your sound files as background music (with the playBackgroundMusic method).

If that doesn't work for you, have a look at [ObjectAL](http://kstenerud.github.com/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/). You'll have more options and greater flexibility. For example, with [ALSource](http://learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/ObjectAL/html/interface_a_l_source.html) you can queue multiple [ALBuffer](http://learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/ObjectAL/html/interface_a_l_buffer.html) objects which represent sound files. That means whenever the source's buffer count decreases to 1 you just queue the next buffer to achieve uninterrupted, sequential playback of multiple sound files (any format).

Because ObjectAL is so awesome (well, I think so :) ) it's included and ready to use in [Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I tried playing another sound in the callback of setBackgroundMusicCompletionListener, but it just isn't fast enough. I am playing music, so the slightest delay will be very noticeable. I preloaded the background sounds aswell, so I guess it will not work.

Comment: I will try your other tips asap :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked using ObjectAL with ALSource and ALBuffer. Creating the different buffers and then queuing them did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single Audio Queue or the RemoteIO Audio Unit, and just fill the callback buffers with raw/PCM audio samples from any file in any order.